# eclipse team ( Mercurial Eclipse ) edit highlighting

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I am trying to move from Netbeans to Eclipse. 
Minor thing bothering me is that Eclipse dosen't seem to have the kinda edit highlighting that Netbeans does.

For example, a new line is automatically highlighted as green. An edit is highlighted as blue. And this happens in an unobtrusive way on the left along with the line numbers( if line numbers are turned on).

Is this some configuration issue or does eclipse team not support it ?

This is specifically for MercurialEclipse plugin.

Comment: http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1987/netbeansedithighlightin.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a heavy eclipse user and as a general rule of thumb, it supports mostly everything.  So problems like these are most likely solved through configuration and/or plugins.

Regarding your specific situation...

Maybe I'm not following your question but it seems you want to look at edits that happen on a file?  When I do this in eclipse, I do so through the subversion plugin (Subclipse) and compare the existing file against a previous version in the repository (to compare against the team's older version of the file) or in local history (to compare against your own version of the file).

As in:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i understand, I can get a diff view thru the context menu. But, what I like and am used to is that it always displays the local changes with respect to the current revision. I have attached a link to an image in my original question. I find this much easier than having to go thru a context menu and getting a diff view. Ans this is available in netbeans for both svn and hg.

Comment: I see. Eclipse does similar highlighting on the side when you make an edit to an unsaved file.  So the functionality is possible, it's just a matter of finding the plugin/extension that does it the way you like.  Apparently, the Subversive plugin allows for a **Team > Show Annotations** feature that turns on something like this. Perhaps the Mercurial plugin offers something similar.  If not, the feature could be requested here: http://javaforge.com/proj/tracker/browseTracker.do?tracker_id=11127

Comment: @smartnut: I was just using eclipse and stumbled on the "Quick Diff" setting. Go to Preferences and type "Quick Diff" in the search box in the upper left corner. You can set the colors for *changes, additions and deletions* as well as the file to compare with (SVN, CVS, Disk). I changed the color for *additions* to green and it looked more similar to your linked image. Also, now that we know the feature's name is "Quick Diff," it should be easier to google...

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what i was looking for. It does the job, after changing the color conspicuous color scheme. I guess, googling failed because we didn't know the term "quick diff".

Answer (score 0):

Also there is great article about this:
http://blog.firdau.si/2010/07/09/eclipse-quick-diff-see-what-changes-youve-made-since-last-checkout/